# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tflite_support.task'

Tags: raspberry-pi, tflite

tflite_support's task library is missing. I've install the tflite_support with `pip install tflite-support`. I've tried using help() function to get the pakage content with `help(tflite_support)` and got the output 'PACKAGE CONTENTS
_pywrap_codegen
_pywrap_flatbuffers    codegen
flatbuffers (package)
metadata
metadata_schema_py_generated
schema_py_generated'. There is no task library inside like how the tflite website shows https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/inference_with_metadata/task_library/object_detector#run_inference_in_python. I get the same result doing it in my window pc. Am I doing anything wrong or the task library is just missing?

Comment: You ever figure this out? I am running on rasp pi B+ Buster image and get this problem.

Answer (score 1):

A quick fix is to compile tflite-support with Python 3.9, 3.10, or 3.11 support by first downloading the published Mac or Ubuntu wheels: https://pypi.org/project/tflite-support-nightly/0.4.4.dev20230623/#files
then running

```bash
pip install ./tflite_support_nightly-0.4.4.dev20230623-cp310-cp310-macosx_10_11_x86_64.whl
```

Note: Change the `pip install` command to match the downloaded wheel.

Referenced from the [following GitHub issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tflite-support/issues/909)

In case the above link stops working you can use: https://pypi.org/project/tflite-support-nightly/#files
Don't forget to change the commands to match the downloaded wheel.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using tflite-support 0.4.1 and it looks like the task module is not supported on Windows:

```py
import flatbuffers
import platform

from tensorflow_lite_support.metadata import metadata_schema_py_generated
from tensorflow_lite_support.metadata import schema_py_generated
from tensorflow_lite_support.metadata.python import metadata
from tflite_support import metadata_writers

if platform.system() != 'Windows':
  # Task Library is not supported on Windows yet.
  from tflite_support import task
```

There's also a note about it in the [task_library docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/inference_with_metadata/task_library/overview).